# Internet Explorer - float & background issue

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml, css-float

I'm having an issue (among many others:) with IE.

Here is my example, there we should see the text "Product":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
#editor_cont {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.product_list {
  float: right;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor_cont">
  <div>Product</div>
  <select class="product_list">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE9< the text "Product" is not displaied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this issue by adding zoom:1 to the div containing the "Product" text.

```
#editor_cont div {
    zoom: 1;
}
```